# Which sentence is correct: "I hope you and her are fine." or "I hope you and she are fine."?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, pronouns, possessive-pronouns

Between the two sentences:

- I hope you and her are fine.
- I hope you and she are fine.

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: The first is certainly incorrect: **her** is an object or a possessive pronoun, never a subject. "I hope you are both fine."

Comment: @WeatherVane this should be the answer

Comment: ...except occasional colloquial usage: "Her indoors told me to keep quiet about it."

Comment: @WeatherVane. Not very clear to me. What constitute(s) the subject in sentence you referred to?

Comment: @Elvis "You and she" are the subjects of the phrase.

Comment: You wouldn't say "Her are fine", so you don't say "You and her are fine" either.

Comment: Elvis, Weather Vane is referring to the British TV series _Minder_, whose protagonist always referred to his wife (never seen on screen) as _'Er indoors_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't very scientific, but the rule of thumb is the absence or presence of a preposition. This has to do with cases, which used to be a feature of the English language but is no longer so: certain vestigial qualities remain, though.

Thus, if a pronoun is used, it's "her" (and "me" and "him" and "them"):

to her, of her, about her, with her, over her, around her.
to me, of me, about me, with me, over me, around me.
to him, of him, with him, etc.
to them, of them, with them, etc.

If not, use "she"(and "I" and "they").

Like this:

"I hope you and **she** are both fine."

Or:

"I hope everything is fine **with** you and **her**."

"It sounded wonderful **to** **me** and **her**."

The same method applies to "who" and "whom." If there's a preposition involved ("of," "to," "about," "with," etc.) - it's "whom." If not, it's "who."

Comment: So what becomes the subject for the " I hope you and she are (both) fine "?

Comment: @Elvis it is clearer if you say it independently. In "you are fine, she is fine" it is clear what the subjects are, and it is more obvious that "you are fine, her is fine" is ungrammatical.

Comment: I was always taught to do this on the basis of removing the other word. So "I hope she is fine" gives you "I hope you and she are fine."  And "I hope all is well with her" gives  you "I hope all is well with you and her." I suppose this is equivalent to what @WeatherVane has already commented.

Comment: @Xanne: Thank you, I stand corrected. A preposition, of course. The appropriate edit is in place.